# Calculate number of "elapsed" elements from ring buffer index

Tags: c, algorithm

Apologies if I have missed any similar post...
I have a ring buffer of `BUFFER_SIZE` elements that stores event data, so every event increases the `buffer_index`, starting at index 0.
Now I have a `check_cyclic()` function that needs to calculate the number of events since last call.
That function does only know the current `buffer_index`, and it stores that value statically to calculate the difference.
It's guaranteed that `BUFFER_SIZE` exceeds the maximum number of events that can happen during cycle time.
So we have to consider that there can have been only one overflow between two cyclic calls. My implementation is as follows:

```
void check_cyclic(int buffer_index)
{
    static unsigned int last_buffer_index = 0;
    static unsigned int events_since_last_call = 0;

    if (buffer_index < last_buffer_index)
    { // overflow occured
        events_since_last_call = buffer_index + 1 + BUFFER_SIZE - last_buffer_index;
    }
    else
    { 
        events_since_last_call = buffer_index + 1 - last_buffer_index;
    }

    last_buffer_index = buffer_index;

    //... do something
}
```

Of course, let the event routine itself increase a counter and reset this in `check_cyclic()` would be more efficient, but let's assume the interface is as given above.
Is there some more efficient way of calculating `events_since_last_call`, maybe if we define some requirements on the ring buffer? "Size must be a power of two" or whatever?

Comment: Yes, if the buffer capacity is a power of two and the indices are `unsigned`, then the difference would simply be `(head - tail) & (capacity - 1)`. I wouldn't worry about performance here though, I would rather concentrate on encapsulating your ring buffer into a separate module, giving it a struct for holding data and making clear, testable ringbuffer functions (e.g. `size_t buff_get_count(struct ringbuff *rb);` or `void buff_enqueue(struct ringbuff *rb, struct event *evt);`)

Comment: What is the `+ 1` for in the calculations of `events_since_last_call`? Shouldn't the number of events since the last call be just the cyclic difference between the indices?